# left shift char array in java

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement and I have 2 string and a delimiter e.g $

```
str_a = "000";
str_b = "00";
```

My requirement is to shift array to left one char at a time.
e.g,

> if I enter 1 str_a = "000" and str_b = "01" print as 000$01
>
> if I enter 3 str_a = "000" and str_b = "13" print as 000$13
>
> if I enter 5 str_a = "001" and str_b = "35" print as 001$35

etc..

This means `str_a` and `str_b` should shift one char every time copying right side element.

Any idea of how to do this fast?

Comment: The speed of this will almost certainly be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you hold the array as a `StringBuilder` and append new characters on the end. You can then remove characters from the start to make it 5 characters long and then split it 2+3.

```
class SplitFixedWidthString {

    // Total length of String.
    final int len;
    // The lengths of the parts to split it into.
    final int[] parts;
    // The current contents of the string.
    final StringBuilder s;
    // The required delimiter.
    final String delimiter;

    public SplitFixedWidthString(String delimiter, char pad, int... parts) {
        this.parts = parts;
        int l = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            l += parts[i];
        }
        this.len = l;
        s = new StringBuilder(len);
        s.setLength(len);
        // Fill it.
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            s.setCharAt(i, pad);
        }
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public void append(char ch) {
        // Add the character.
        s.append(ch);
        // Remove any spare at the front.
        if (s.length() > len) {
            s.delete(0, s.length() - len);
        }
    }

    public String[] parts() {
        // Roll out into an array of parts.
        String[] p = new String[parts.length];
        int start = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            p[i] = s.substring(start, start + parts[i]);
            start += parts[i];
        }
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Roll out all parts as a String.
        StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
        String[] p = parts();
        boolean first = true;
        for (String s : p) {
            if (!first) {
                r.append(delimiter);
            }
            r.append(s);
            first = false;
        }
        return r.toString();
    }

}

public void test() {
    SplitFixedWidthString s = new SplitFixedWidthString("$", '0', 3, 2);
    char[] test = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
    for (char c : test) {
        s.append(c);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: for this input 
SplitFixedWidthString s = new SplitFixedWidthString("$", 3, 2);
char[] test = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};

Output 
   $  1
by default empty space coming , I need default 000$01 like this
I want to replace empty space with default value is 0
please anybody help

Comment: @prGD - Then you should initially fill `s` with your required padding character (after `setLength`). It currently uses the default which prints as a space.

Comment: thanks, its working
  `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   s.insert(i, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it that way.

```
// create a StringBuilder which holds the whole string
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000");
sb.append("1");
sb.deleteCharAt(0);

// when the StringBuilder has been changed initialize your substrings
String strA = sb.substring(0, 3);
String strB = sb.substring(3, 5);

System.out.println("strA = " + strA);
System.out.println("strB = " + strB);
```